# How to avoid embarrassing situations when I have sweaty hands?

Tags: personal-care, comfort, office

I suffer excessive sweating in my hands, and that causes me embarrassing situations like, when I shake hands with others, being asked to fill a paper form (and return it soaking).

Of course, I can use a tissue (or handkerchief) to dry my hands, but that will keep it dry for just a few seconds.

Also wearing gloves is not suitable for many situations and will make me look weird.

Is there any other way to deal with these situations easily?

Comment: I'm sure a doctor could prescribe something for this condition. For example, there are high-potency antiperspirants available only by prescription.

Comment: make the other person uncomfortable, so he sweats and therefore thinks is its sweat and not yours. *JK*

Comment: @BrettFromLA I tried many of these antiperspirants, but they're no help with extreme conditions like me, sometimes sweat (literally) dribbles off my hand.

Comment: @lois6b I guess I need to post another question on how to make someone so uncomfortable even before shaking hands with him :P ;)

Comment: I used to put my hands in cold green tea, it will shrink the skin! No wet hands for me :) anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a form of [hyperhidrosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperhidrosis). I have found that washing and drying hands on regular intervals with soap or other antibacterial liquids causes less sweat (I drink a lot of water and so I wash my hands thoroughly when I go to the washroom).

I have also noticed that when I get nervous (meeting new people, doing new tasks etc) the palm sweating increases. If you have the same case then try becoming more confident, it helps to a degree.

If all else fails, let the other person know. Say "sorry, I have got sweaty hands" and then let the other person decide whether to continue with the shaking ritual or not.

Comment: If you can't easily wash your hands regularly, consider carrying a small pack of wet wipes.

Answer (score 2):

I can't promise either of these will work sufficiently, but you might try..

- A dry antiperspirant spray on your hands
- Talcum/Baby powder, try rubbing it into your hands

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't help too.

Comment: Have u tried drinking less fluids?

Comment: @Fennekin Yes, and my hands sweat even after 16 hours of totally no fluid.. unfortunately it's a problem with the neural control of sweat glands.. nothing to do with fluids.

Answer (score 2):

At least for shaking hands, don't be overly secretive about it. It is somewhat common here for men who leave the bathroom with their hands still wet from washing to say, "My hands are wet" with a quick laugh and offer their elbow or forearm instead. Or they quickly wipe their hand on their pants before extending it to you. People understand. And laughing will get you out of many awkward situations, not just with sweaty hands.

More generally: if it's not a big deal to you, it won't be a big deal to them.