# Sweaty Palms, when writing literature essay

Tags: stationery

Disclaimer: I am not sure if this question needs to be here or not.

I am having my mid-terms and stress is rolling in!

I have business as subject and had to write literature review that means minimum of 10-15 pages in total. And usually my hands get sweaty and its hard to write.

Any hacks that would be welcomed.

Comment: This sounds like a combination medical/psychological problem, not really amenable to life hacks.

Comment: I put my hands in cold green tea from time to time, that's solve my problem :)

Comment: Baby Powder would work.

Answer (score 1):

A thin pair of gloves made of breathable fabric?

Answer (score 1):

You can bring along a hand towel and use it whenever you need, or use your handkerchief if you cannot bring a towel.

I also recommend washing your hands thoroughly with soap and water and drying them before your review. It can delay the sweating (depending on the stress level)

Also, see my [comment](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/15108/how-to-avoid-embarrassing-situations-when-i-have-sweaty-hands/15131#15131) on this question for some helpful tips and insight on sweaty palms.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is sweat getting on the exam paper. To prevent that, I've used a (blank) piece of paper which I'd place underneath my writing hand. This would prevent the exam paper from getting dirty.